# I want to change the DatePicker Style of UWP

Tags: datepicker, uwp, styles

I want to change the DatePicker Style of UWP as shown below.

I want year to come first and month to come second.

I modified the style but it does not work.

What should I do?

Thank you for your reply.

[image]

Comment: Firstly, could you please share the modified style you are using? Secondly, are you trying to make this change to accomodate a cultural style of displaying dates?

Comment: Solved by Sunteen Wu - MSFT answer.
1. Style is the extent to which only the column position is changed in the default style.
2. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/use-global-ready-formats):

> There are many different ways to properly display dates and times. Different regions and cultures use different conventions for the order of day and month in the date, for the separation of hours and minutes in the time, and even for what punctuation is used as a separator.

If you use [date and time picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/date-and-time) controls, these will automatically use the date and time formats for the user's preferred language and region. So the order is defined by the user's preferred language and region that you should not be able to change them by the style of `DatePicker`.

The first image you showed above seems like preferred language is `en-US` and home region is `US`. For scenarios where you provide different functionality based on the user's language, region, or cultural preferences, Windows gives you a way to access those preferences, through [`Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences). And the second image seems like preferred language is Chinese. The preferred language can be override by property [`PrimaryLanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages#Windows_Globalization_ApplicationLanguages_PrimaryLanguageOverride). Pay attention that the `PrimaryLanguageOverride` property should only be set to languages that are available for the user.

So if you change the prefer language to Chinese the `DataPicker` may be shown in order `year-mouth-day`. Also formats need be changed as the second image show. Code as follows:

```
<DatePicker  BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"  MinWidth="190" DayFormat="{}{day.integer(2)}" MonthFormat="month.numeric" YearFormat="{}{year.full(4)}"   />
```

Code behind

```
  ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "zh-Hans-CN";
```

And the result

[image]

To respect the user's Language and Cultural Preferences, this may not be recommended to change.

Comment: I would like to comment that if you set the PrimaryLanguageOverride then it's value is persisted across subsequent launches of the application unless you reset it.

Comment: @Corcus, yes, you're right the the property page I uploaded above has already mentioned. So that I also recommend not to do this although this can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is well.